# GCP - Kubernetes Ingress Backend service unhealthy

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have deployed a SAS Viya programming on a pod.This has SASStudio running on port 80. I am trying to expose the SAS Studio using the nodeport and Ingress through below yaml files. But in the GCP console, the backend service is displayed has unhealthy and if I try to access the Ip either it is hitting default backend or page not found. I am able to access the service using the cluster IP and node IP along with the port number.

If I use LoadBalancer service instead of Ingress, I am able to access the service using the Loadbalancer Ip.

When using the Ingress, the backend service is shown as unhealthy.

I have used the curl command with node Ip and nodeport Ip. Below is the result.

```
   [root@k8jumphost doc]# curl -ILS "10.142.0.19:30100"
    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    Date: Fri, 01 Feb 2019 07:53:31 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
    Location: http://10.142.0.19:30100/SASStudio
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

    HTTP/1.1 302
    Date: Fri, 01 Feb 2019 07:53:32 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
    Location: /SASStudio/
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked

    HTTP/1.1 200
    Date: Fri, 01 Feb 2019 07:53:34 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
    Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:;
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
    Content-Language: en-US
    Content-Length: 7836

    [root@k8jumphost doc]# cat sas-analytics-ingress.yaml
    ---
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: sas-programming-ingress
      labels:
        app: sas-programming
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: sas-programming
        http:
          paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: sas-programming-svc-nodeport
              servicePort: 80


        [root@k8jumphost doc]# cat sas-analytics-nodeport.yaml
    ---

    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: sas-programming-svc-nodeport
      labels:
        app: sas-programming
    spec:
      selector:
        app: sas-programming
      ports:
      - name: http
        nodePort: 30100
        port: 80
        targetPort: 80
      - name: cas
        nodePort: 30200
        port: 5570
        targetPort: 5570
      type: NodePort

[root@k8jumphost doc]# cat sas-analytics.yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sas-programming-deployment
  labels:
    app: sas-programming
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sas-programming
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      hostname: sas-programming
      containers:
      - name: sas-programming
        image: <location of the image>
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5570
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: CASENV_CAS_VIRTUAL_HOST
          value: "sas-programming"
        - name: CASENV_CAS_VIRTUAL_PORT
          value: "30300"
```

I suspect the redirection on the / is resulting this error. Can anyone please help me, what should be added to the deployment file to overcome this error.

Answer (score 2):

I think the fact that your backend in GCP is unhealthy is indicative that you may not have health endpoint on your container. Have a look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#loadbalancing. You would need `readinessProbe` and `livenessProbe` in your deployment yaml.